# Was the NAACP slow in acting for the rights of Sherman Ware?

Tags: united-states, criminology, discrimination

In [What the NAACP can learn from George Zimmerman](http://dailycaller.com/2013/05/07/what-the-naacp-can-learn-from-george-zimmerman/#ixzz2ZJ80qIwv), George Zimmerman's brother Robert Zimmerman Jr. claimed that the organization was slow to act on the beating of homeless African-American Sherman Ware by Justin Collison, the son of a policeman:

> My brother George Zimmerman, who lived in Sanford at the time, fought
>   for justice on Ware’s behalf. George tried to enlist the help of the
>   local chapter of the NAACP. He called their office, but they told him
>   that they didn’t have the resources to help.
>
> ...
>
> Collison turned himself in on January 3, 2011. That’s when the NAACP
>   suddenly entered the fray. The same organization that days before
>   hadn’t had the resources to help George announced plans to meet with
>   the new police chief and ask why Collison hadn’t been charged with a
>   hate crime.

Is Robert's description of what the NAACP did and didn't do correct, and the full story, or are there inaccuracies or omissions from this description?

I came across a [Media Matters for America](http://mediamatters.org/blog/2013/05/08/daily-caller-gives-zimmermans-brother-who-sent/193972) blog post mentioning this piece, but it doesn't try to directly rebut the claims.